# Is MySQL installed by default with OS X Leopard 10.5 or 10.6

Tags: macos, mac, mysql, osx-leopard

If so where can I find the installation?

Answer (score 8):

no, it isn’t—only on server version:

http://developer.apple.com/internet/opensource/osdb.html

Answer (score 5):

It's not installed by default in Mac OS X 10.5. You can install it via a package manager like MacPorts, or from the package on the [MySQL web site](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mac-os-x-installation.html).

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe it is.  The easiest thing to do is to download it from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.1.html#macosx-dmg) (mysql.com)  I install both it and the startup item included in the package.

Answer (score 0):

It's not installed in 10.6 either.-

Answer (score 0):

If you follow [these instructions](http://hivelogic.com/articles/compiling-mysql-on-snow-leopard/), you can install MySQL by hand on Snow Leopard. (There are versions of the instructions for Leopard accessible on the site as well). It also contains instructions for registering MySQL with `launchd`, allowing you to just forget about it (it will be running if your computer is running), and also turn it off when you need to do so.

Answer (score 0):

As a side note: when using Time Machine you may be interested in excluding the log files, which by default are hidden in a directory that even an admin account cannot access:

```
ls -la /usr/local/mysql-5.0.51a-osx10.5-x86
[..]
drwxr-x---   4 _mysql  wheel    136 Jul 10 23:06 data
[..]
```

Or, change the MySQL settings to move the logs to some temp folder.

(To remove existing MySQL log files from the backup disk, you need to [run Time Machine as root](https://superuser.com/questions/35152/how-do-i-retrieve-files-from-time-machine-backups-from-another-computer/35309#35309).)