# Does my MacBook Pro have MySQL installed by default?

Tags: mac, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is MySQL installed by default with OS X Leopard 10.5 or 10.6](https://superuser.com/questions/37959/is-mysql-installed-by-default-with-os-x-leopard-10-5-or-10-6)

I have a new macbookpro, does it come with mysql or do I install it myself?

Answer (score 0):

Open up a terminal and try the mysql cli client:

```
mysql -V
```

That should print a version string, if it's installed.

Also, as alluded to by Matthew Rankin, this type of question belongs on https://superuser.com/.