# How do I see what files are new in a Time Machine backup?

Tags: macos, time-machine

As I understand it, Time Machine creates hard links for all the previous files in a backup, so each timestamped backup folder appears as a full snapshot of the files at the time of the backup. How can I find out which files are *new* for a given backup and which files were carried forward from the previous backup?

Comment: See also the notes on `timedog` (command line) and TimeTracker (GUI) at [Verifying Time Machine backups](http://superuser.com/questions/47628/verifying-time-machine-backups/87591#87591).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BackupLoupe](http://www.soma-zone.com/BackupLoupe/) is $1, excellent, and does just this.

And yes, it does use hard links. This [article](http://arstechnica.com/apple/reviews/2007/10/mac-os-x-10-5.ars/14) (part of a 10.5 review on arstechnica) explains how Time Machine works and is a very interesting read.

Answer (score 1):

If Time Machine is actually using hard links, you can use 'ls -l' to display the link count for a file.  In theory, new files will have a link count of 1.  For example:

```
  $ touch foo
  $ ls -l foo
  -rw-r--r--  1 lars  staff  0 Dec  4 00:22 foo
```

The second field is the link count.  Let's create a link:

```
  $ ln foo bar
  $ ls -l foo bar
  -rw-r--r--  2 lars  staff  0 Dec  4 00:22 bar
  -rw-r--r--  2 lars  staff  0 Dec  4 00:22 foo
```

Note that the link count has increased.

You can use the 'find' command to find all files with a single link:

```
$ find /path/to/backup -links 1 -print
```

Comment: That's what I thought, too, but it's not that easy. If a *folder* has been "carried forward," then there will be a hard link to just the folder. The files in the folder won't have additional links, so if a folder remains unchanged for several backups, the link counts for those files will remain at 1 even though they're actually very old.

Answer (score 0):

## Compare snapshots

In Lion or greater:

- use the `compare` verb of [tmutil](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man8/tmutil.8.html).