# How to check for corruption in a backup?

Tags: backup

When making a backup, what is the best method to check for corruption?

In my case I have frequent power cuts to a powered external drive.

Using OS X and Linux

Comment: For OS X: [Verifying Time Machine backups](http://superuser.com/questions/47628/verifying-time-machine-backups).

Answer (score 0):

As you recognize, a bad backup is worse than useless, since it lulls the user into a false sense of security.

First, get a UPS for the external HDD. It might be easier to power the drive from a battery on a charger, rather than a commercial UPS, since many external HDD's use just a single-ended 12 VDC supply.

Second, set the backup/imaging software to verify the file automatically. However, if there are frequent power outages, the *verify* operation might fail due to that, rather than due to a bad file.