# Finder: Open folder as another user

Tags: macos, mac, unix, nautilus, file-permissions

I just would like some simple protection of my files, and from my point of view, there's nothing like unix permissions system. Chmoding and chowning folders and files just gives me the flexibility I'm seeking. I would like Finder was more friendly and instead of telling me "You don't have permissions" just asked me the credentials with proper access rights.

Do you know if there's a way of accomplishing this? I used this a lot on Gnome's Nautilus and I don't feel like opening a command-line for browsing my non system or coding related files.

Comment: Not what you want, but to (temporarily) run *all* Finder windows as root, see the details at [How do I retrieve files from Time Machine backups from another computer?](http://superuser.com/questions/35152/how-do-i-retrieve-files-from-time-machine-backups-from-another-computer/35309#35309)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know that there's a way to do this because you'd have to re-open Finder as the other user in your user space.

You can use the `su -l [username]` command in Terminal to login to the command line as that user and then type `cd[space]` (that's the spacebar) and then drag the folder in question into the terminal window to avoid typing the full folder path.

Comment: I already knew this but I liked the drag to paste full path trick. Thanks for the tip