# Copy / restore files from Time Machine Backup Volume without Permission Denied Error

Tags: macos, finder, time-machine, cp, pathfinder

On new MacBooks (Big Sur, 11.2.3, M1) disk space is costly, because there is no alternative to apple parts. So i have NOT used Migration Assistant, to copy over all the old files from Time Machine Backup. (Same user name & number on the new Mac)

But when i try to copy files manually from the old Time Machine Volume using **Path Finder** i get a **Permission Denied Error**.
So i tried to copy using the terminal with `cp` command. This worked when doing it with a `sudo` in front.

But then i have problems with the copies. They **can not be written and not deleted** anymore.

Copying with `sudo cp -RX source target` worked better. The files were write- and deleteable, but they **loose i.e. their original date**.

**How can i copy from a Time Machine Backup without all these problems?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question. I found the very simple solution many weeks later, because i'm usually not using the original Finder:

**Use the original FINDER to copy from a Time Machine Backup**, instead of Path Finder or the `cp` command!

Doing so produces a copy without having the mentioned problems.
BTW: After i did this the first time, now also using the `cp` command works without the problems.

Background:

Time Machine alters the ACL (Access Control List) of all the backuped files, to make sure, the backup will not be deleted. Copying using the original Finder cares about this special case and removes these ACL entries. In [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/361925/permissions-restoring-from-time-machine-finder-copy-vs-cp-copy#answer-362014), you can read more about this.

But it looks like copying the first time with original Finder, seems to change also something in the system or on the the backup volume. Because now, also copying with `cp` command works  without keeping the problematic ACLs entries. Even after reboot. While to copy with Path Finder stays problematic from the Time Machine volume.